In Magento2 Move CAPTCHA to Below Payment Options on Checkout Page?
I have added Magento Native Captcha in checkout page.
Issue: Captcha is showing before payment methods list. When we change the payment method the captcha is getting reloaded.
Is there any way to move captcha under payment methods, so that its value will not be reloaded every time we change the payment method?
or can we stop reloading captcha on every change event of payment methods?


A simple approach to achieve this can be:

Create a custom module or use an existing module. Let's say Stack_Custom.
Under app/code/Stack/Custom/view/frontend/layout folder, create checkout_index_index.xml file and put the following content:

`
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="before-login-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-login-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- before login form fields -->
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="additional-login-form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">additional-login-form-fields</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- additional login form fields -->
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="place-order-captcha" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="place-order-captcha" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/checkout/placeOrderCaptcha</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">place-order-captcha</item>
                                                                            <item name="formId" xsi:type="string">payment_processing_request</item>
                                                                            <item name="configSource" xsi:type="string">checkoutConfig</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>


Clean cache and refresh the checkout page.

Now Magento will start showing native captcha under each payment method.

thank you @Mohit_kumar_arora sir, its working for me......

To address the issue of the CAPTCHA reloading every time the payment method is changed on the Magento 2.4 checkout page, you have a couple of options:
Option 1: Move CAPTCHA Under Payment Methods
Moving the CAPTCHA under the payment methods section ensures that its value remains unaffected when the payment method is changed. To do this, you'll need to customize the checkout_index_index.xml layout file or create a custom module that adjusts the position of the CAPTCHA block.

Override checkout_index_index.xml:

Create a custom module or theme override.
Locate the checkout_index_index.xml file.
Move the CAPTCHA block under the payment methods section.

<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Checkout\Captcha" name="checkout.captcha" template="Magento_Captcha::checkout/captcha.phtml">
            <container name="captcha-wrapper" as="captcha-wrapper" after="checkout.payment.methods">
                <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Checkout\Captcha" name="captcha" template="Magento_Captcha::checkout/captcha.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>


Adjust the Layout:

Update the layout to ensure that the CAPTCHA is correctly positioned and only loads once.



Option 2: Prevent CAPTCHA Reload on Payment Method Change
If moving the CAPTCHA is not an option, you can prevent the CAPTCHA from reloading every time a payment method is changed. This can be done by customizing the JavaScript in the checkout page.

Customize Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/list.js:

Override the payment-list.js file to prevent unnecessary reloading of the CAPTCHA when a payment method is selected.

define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators'
], function (ko, Component, rendererList, additionalValidators) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/payment-method-list'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // Custom logic to prevent CAPTCHA reloading
            this.isCaptchaLoaded = false;
            this.paymentMethodSubscribe();
        },
        paymentMethodSubscribe: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.isCaptchaLoaded = true;
            this._super();
        }
    });
});


Apply Custom JavaScript:

Apply the customized JavaScript to the checkout page to ensure the CAPTCHA doesn't reload on every payment method change.



Testing and Deployment
After implementing either of these solutions, clear the cache and test the changes on the checkout page to ensure the CAPTCHA behaves as expected.
Final Notes

Option 1 is generally the more straightforward approach as it avoids the need for custom JavaScript, but it depends on your specific requirements and whether moving the CAPTCHA is feasible within your checkout flow.
Option 2 provides a more sophisticated solution that avoids disrupting the existing layout but requires more in-depth customization.

Choose the approach that best fits your needs.

thanks for your comment...but i tried both options its not working any options for me....
